# Error: NULL entry for column 1 in sqlite3 database

Tags: mysql, objective-c, uitableview, sqlite

I have a database made in sqlite3 with the following conditions

Table name: Stock

```
Column 1: ID integer primary key
Column 2: Name text
Column 3: Price integer
Column 4: Quantity integer
```

When calling on 'select * from stock;' in sqlite 3 I get the following back;

```
1|Tomato Sauce|3.99|7
```

And the price and quantity values are displayed correctly on my UITableView - as seen here; [image: UITableView]

The ID is also being displayed, however that is not the intended field I wish to display. I want to display the product name, which falls into column 1. Below is the code which associates the objects I've created to the sqlite3 database;

```
-(void)readDataFromDatabase{
[self.stock removeAllObjects];

sqlite3 *database;

if (sqlite3_open([self.databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
    char *sqlStatement = "select * from stock";
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){
        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW){
            char *n = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1);
            float p = (float)sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 2);
            int q = sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 3);

            NSString *name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:n];
            NSNumber *price = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:p];
            NSNumber *quantity = [NSNumber numberWithInt:q];

            Data *data = [[Data alloc] initWithData:name thePrice:price theQuantity:quantity];
            [self.stock addObject:data];
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
}
sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

The only way for me to get my simulator to launch and not get an error is to change the column for the following to 0 (ID) instead of 1 (Name);

```
char *n = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0);
```

Whenever I change the 0 to depict the Name column, the simulator crashes and I get lead to the main.m file linked to the AppDelegate. The following error is displayed in the debug area;

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString'
```

**From my understanding it is failing due it feeling that the compiler is crashing as a NULL value is being fed into the constant char* which is of stringWithUTF8String. However, after doing the 'select * from stock;' I can confirm the data is being stored correctly in the database.**

Comment: Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The first column does not containt strings. If you dont want the ID column, why are you writing a query that returns it?

Comment: I originally had ID incase I needed to have it returned. However, what do you mean the first column doesn't contain strings? It's formatted in 'text' and returns 'Tomato Sauce' in sqlite 3?

Comment: The first column returned by the query is the ID.

Comment: I thought the ID column would be listed as 0? then what column number is the Name? Because the price and quantity are columns 2 and 3 respectively?

Comment: The first index is `0`. Anyway, add `n = n ? n : "(NULL)";` before calling `stringWithUTF8String`.